# Memory leak in UIButton setFont

Tags: iphone, fonts, uibutton, iboutlet

Hope you all doing well, I am getting a memory leak while setting the font of UIButton. This is the code which I am using to set the font,

```
    [MyBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
```

whereas MyBtn is connected to IBOoutlet and I am not allocating memory to it.

I don't see any thing wrong in the code. Hopefully someone will help me out, I will be really thankful.

Regards,
Mohammad Salman

Answer (score 0):

There is no leak just for this line of code.

It's possible that Instruments has a false positive because the fonts are cached (i.e. `-retain`ed by UIKit).

Comment: Thanks for reply, In instrument the responsible library is UIKit whereas in extended detail it is pointing my code,
Do you think I should go for apple technical support or submit my app ?